# Vulnerability scanner for asp.net flags cross site scripting

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, xss, owasp

I am running netspark vulnerability test and it flags following url

> http://localhost:54923/search/'ns='netsparker(0x005AAD)

I am not able to understand what `'ns='netsparker(0x005AAD)` is this part or how to fix this issue i am sanitizing input `/search/searchkeyword` to make user ENcoding the input also

User enter the keyword in search input box and then page is redirected with search page with the search keyword `http://localhost:54923/search/apple`

1>  it doesn't contain and JS script

```
 if (filterInput.Contains("onmouseover") || filterInput.Contains("script") || filterInput.Contains("</style>") || filterInput.Contains("</script>") || filterInput.Contains("<") || filterInput.Contains("%3c") || filterInput.Contains("?") || filterInput.Contains("%3f") || filterInput.Contains("alert") )
            {
                search = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(filterInput);
                Response.Write("Invalid Search");
                Response.End();
            }
```

2> I am adding below line to web.config to make it bit more secure

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" enable="true"  encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Based on this i have few question

1. What is 'ns='netsparker(0x005AAD) in the url does it represent js
2. How can i prevent this
3. Measures which i have taken is fine or i need to do more.

After adding few security steps, netsparket still flags it as xss. How can i fix this so that its not flagged

Comment: try search/javascript:alert(1) 
would it work?

Comment: can you also post more info? how is this string being handeled on ur backend? can you post the code?

Comment: @shawkyz1, When i add `/search/javascript:alert(1)` to link asp.net webform generates an default `response Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:). ` and even the code i am sanitizing input for by checking if it doesnt contain any JS and also i am using HTML Encode on top of that also to have an additional protection

Answer (score 1):

Basically the current code sanitization is based on a blacklist which is a **bad practice**.

In this specific case you don't need to sanitize but rather **Encode the incoming input**.

The ASP.Net Input validation in also based on blacklist which is also not **secure**.

Comment: I am encoding inputs before displaying them on page in case i need to. I am not sure what you mean by blacklist

Comment: blacklisting is exactly what you are doing here. you specified for example when there's "onmouseover" or "script" you will encoded. but what if there was an onclick event or onload event or whatever javascript event? 
you can't cover all these cases

Comment: that's why if u wanting to take a listing approach it's better to "allow" some tags/attributes/content instead of specifying what's prohibited