# Cross site scripting vulnerabilities for onmouseover in url

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, xss

A website was audited for vulnerabilities and it had flagged XSS for many pages which, from my point of view, do not appear to be vulnerable as I don't display any data captured from form the page or the URL (such as query string).

Acunetix flagged the following URL as XSS by adding some javacript code

`http://www.example.com/page-one//?'onmouseover='pU0e(9527)`

Report:

> GET /page-one//?'onmouseover='pU0e(9527)'bad=' HTTP/1.1
>   Referer: https://www.example.com/
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Authorization: Basic FXvxdAfafmFub25cfGb=
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Host: example.com

So, how could this be vulnerable or is it possible that it's vulnerable?

Above all, if `onmouseover` can be added as XSS then how will it be affected?

Comment: You don't have to use a query string variable to be vulnerable. You could have something in the source that echos the current URL (for example). Try copying the URL and checking your browser's console.

Comment: @gray Can you please elaborate more on what you are said

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vulnerability scanner for asp.net flags cross site scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052565/vulnerability-scanner-for-asp-net-flags-cross-site-scripting)

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for more information, I'll post my response as an answer.

The main question as I see it:

#### Can there still be an XSS vulnerability from the query string if I don't use any of the parameters in my code?

Well, if they *actually* aren't used at all, then it should not be possible. **However**, there are subtle ways that you could be using them that you may have overlooked. (Posting the actual source code would be useful here).

One example would be something like this:

```
Response.Write("<a href='" + 
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) + "'>share this link!</a>
```

This would put the entire URL in the body of the web page. The attacker can make use of the query string even though they aren't mapped to variables because the full URL is written in the response. Keep in mind it could also be in a hidden field.

Be careful writing out values like `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` or `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery`.

Some tips:

- Confirm that the scanner is not reporting a false positive by opening the link in a modern browser like Chrome. Check the console for an error about "XSS Auditor" or similar.
- Use an antixss library to encode untrusted output before writing to the response.
- read this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I don't understand the meaning behind the `onmouseover` comment enough to answer it. Basically, if an attacker can add a mouseover event to some link on your page, then when the user hovers over the link, then the attacker can cause the page to execute arbitrary javascript which can be used to steal cookies, modify the web page, and anything else done via XSS.